# link to open in new window in a link webpart SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010

Any ideas on how to make a link in a link webpart open in a new window?
 Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean you have a list web part and it contains Link content type.  You wish the Link content type to open in a new window.  My only suggestion is that you use a custom XSLT for your List WebPart and render the xhtml link tag with a target attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with jQuery. Get all links in the webpart and add the target attribute:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // selector: get all links in the link webpart, check for unique (parent) class
  $('selector').attr('target', '_blank');
});
```